# samba public share on ubuntu 14.10 not working no matter what i try

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, share, anonymous

I have a share folder in this location and im trying to share using samba **(Version 4.1.11)** in **ubuntu 14.10**
/media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/share

/media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/ is a mounted partition /dev/sda1 .. mounted as ext4 .. [image]

This is my share permissions for above folder..

[image]

**and samba configuration is as follows**

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]

workgroup = REXXXXPSL

   hosts allow = 127. 172. 172.16.

   load printers = yes

   security = user
   map to guest = Bad User
   dns proxy = no

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[shaa]
    path = "/media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/share"
    force user = nobody
    force group = nogroup
    nt acl support = no
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

I'm getting this error in the windows pc .. no matter what i google and try..

error is **"you might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the Administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. Access is denied. "**

[image]

**net config workstation** is as below..

[image]

**testparm results**

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[shaa]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        workgroup = REXXXXPSL
        map to guest = Bad User
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 127., 172., 172.16.

[shaa]
        path = "/media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/share"
        force user = nobody
        force group = nogroup
        read only = No
        create mask = 0755
        guest ok = Yes
        nt acl support = No
```

ps : my ubuntu pc ip is 172.16.30.110 and the network range is 172.16.0.0./16

Not sure where im doing silly, cannot figure out though i have spend lot more time checking configurations and similar threads in google.. Any help/tip would be greatly appreciated as im fully stuck in this no matter what i do ..

I have added login to my smb.conf file 
by adding

```
log level = 3
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%p

max log size = 5000
debug timestamp = yes
```

then used `tail -f log.%p | grep 172.16.100.190`  (where 172.16.100.190 is the windows clent )

Below is the error output...

```
Allowed connection from 172.16.100.190 (172.16.100.190)
com-dc01-hof (ipv4:172.16.100.190:1644) connect to service IPC$ initially as user nobody (uid=65534, gid=65534) (pid 6096)
com-dc01-hof (ipv4:172.16.100.190:1644) closed connection to service IPC$
process_local_master_announce: from COM-DC01-HOF<46> IP 172.16.100.190 to REXXXXPSL<1e> for server COM-DC01-HOF.
process_local_master_announce: from COM-DC01-HOF<46> IP 172.16.100.190 to REXXXXPSL<1e> for server COM-DC01-HOF.
check_for_master_browser_success: Local master browser for workgroup REXXXXPSL exists at IP 172.16.100.190 (just checking).
check_for_master_browser_success: Local master browser for workgroup REXXXXPSL exists at IP 172.16.100.190 (just checking).
```

**iptables status..**

[image]

Comment: I replicated your configuration in my Ubuntu server and was able to access the samba share from a windows box. I suspect this might be firewall related, can you post the output of `iptables -L -n` and confirm all ports are open.

Comment: hi Daniel .. First of all grateful for you kind efforts .. I have added firewall rules status at the end of the question.. seems iptables disabled.. can this be a windows firewall thing ? or are there anything other than iptables in ubuntu ? such a selinux in centos ?

Comment: hi finally after wasting lot more time, i found a workaround.. instead of mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/ location i have mounted it to a folder /test .. now its working.. should be a samba bag of some form.. looks like samba 4.+ is shaving issues with long strings... such as /media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a workaround.. 
Not sure what is the reason, yet by changing mounting point to a different location fix the issue.. instead of mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/aravinda/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/ location i have mounted it to a folder /testt under same user and group nobody:nogroup and 777 permission as it was.. now its working

[image]

**if someone figure out the reason, please do comment or reply.. I just wonder why its like this!!!**